# Conversion of unix file listing time to epoch time

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

A quick question. When do a `ll` command in unix, we get the file listing the timestamp at which it was modified/created. Usually it will be in the format of **MMM dd HH:MM**. How can i get this converted to epoch time?

For ex: `ll abc.txt`

Output: **-rw-rw-r-- 1 maria_dev maria_dev  105 Mar 25 12:00 abc.txt**

How can I convert this Mar 25 12:00 to epoch time.

Note: Here year is not being listed also

Comment: Do you want to *convert* a previous `ls -l` output, or change the time-style when `ls -l` is run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you’re using GNU `ls`, you can use [its `--time-style` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Formatting-file-timestamps.html):

```
ls -l --time-style=+%s
```

Comment: Or `TIME_STYLE=+%s ls -l` also.